# How to make Intellij give propper recommendations in code?

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm participating in a new project, but Intellij dont want to give me the recommendations when typing in code. I will ilustrate this with the following example:

My Intellij looks like this, when I type in the "." after the "GenerationType": [image]

The one of my teammates looks like this after doing the same:

[image]

He gets good recommendations, also in the project-structure on the left, the java calsses have different Symbols.

My guess is that Intellij doesn't recognise the projectstructure on my machine, but I followed the exact same steps my teammate did when cloning the project.

Also Intellij doesnt ask me anything about the project when starting it (anything like indexing or anything about the dependencies, nothing like that). I already updated Intellij to the newest version and tried to delete and re-clone the project.

Any hints what I could try here to fix that siutation and make Intellij give me propper recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one worked for me:

on the left side:

[image]

I right-clicked on "pom.xml", then on maven (second last entry) and on "reload project".